# How do you use a wobble board for strengthening core muscles

Tags: core

I bought a wobble board for strengthening core muscles, I believe mine to be weak on the basis that I suffer from backache, find sit-ups difficult etcetera.

But having bought it I find it doesn't come with any documentation and internet searches indicate it main use is for improving ankle strength.

Just standing on it does seem to engage my core and is not easy but manageable, but I'm looking for how to use it properly. Also some way of measuring my core strength would be useful.

Comment: I think you'd have better luck with planks, squats, and some single leg exercises. Not trying to be unhelpful, but I don't think the wobble board is solving a lot of problems for many people.

Comment: I find with plank because it's so static it's mentally tiring to just hang in there as long as you can, with squats I don't feel it's exercising my core at all (perhaps because I have problems with my glutes as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people I've known using wobble boards use it [to improve balance](http://www.livestrong.com/article/105767-wobble-board-exercises/) by creating a somewhat predictable unstable surface off of which you can work. In terms of core training, the general usage I've seen is combining with with traditional core exercises such as planks and using it to add instability to make yourself work harder. For example, you might try to do your [plank with your arms on the flat side of the wobble board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUZMOUkVwpE), forcing you to remain in a much more static position, and to use your muscles to remain stable. Similarly, you can do push-ups on a wobble-board to use your core more during the exercise.

Comment: Okay but standing on the board seems to use my core muscles, especially if I then alternately close eyes, does that strengthen core muscles or not ?

Comment: You do have to use your core muscles to stand on a wobble board, the same as that you need to use your core muscles to stand on one leg, or to stand at all. I think the general argument goes that you just aren't using enough of your core muscles in the typical balancing exercise on the wobble board compared to things like plank variations.

Comment: Right, but if you are coming from a low base like myself and you can feel it in your core as I can that should be a beneficial first step shouldnt it.

Comment: :) Yes, standing on a wobble board does engage core muscles, and more so than just standing in place. And if you're getting a sufficient workout from that, cool. But in general, it's considered to be a secondary aspect and there are better ways of engaging the core muscles. That said, standing on the wobble board does have benefits, such as being able to watch TV while on it.

Comment: The video is interesting I always you just stayed motionless when doing the plank

Comment: Ah. That would be a static plank. A dynamic plank is where you do a standard plank, but have added motion. The rule of thumb I've heard is that once you can hold a 90 second static plank without trouble, learning to hold it longer isn't really going to help much, so you should start going into variations. The other direction to take is maintaining constant tension, squeezing your stomach, back, and gluteal muscles as hard as you can while maintaining the plank. Russian Kettlebell Challenge planks is what some call the latter.